Why does graphene tend to break during mechanical exfoliation?
Is there any specific physical reason that can explain why graphene produced by tape exfoliation tends to break into fragments instead of remaining as a original size perfect piece? Some of the literature I found only briefly mentions that it's due to certain forces causing graphene to fracture, resulting in the production of small pieces. If possible, providing references to relevant literature would be appreciated. Thanks for the assistance.

Because it is really fragile? One layer of atoms isn't much.
